# Can't submit ajax forms in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a query script that isn't working on IE8. All the script does is send a form via ajax. Please help if you can. On sumbit the page refreshes like IE doesn't know it's an ajax form.

I changed the button type from submit to button and now when you click the button nothing happens. It seems this is a well known problem with ie8.

```
<input class="nice-s" 
       type="submit" 
       id="send" 
       name="login_submit" 
       style="width:150px"  
       value="GET SEATED" 
       onClick="self.location=this.href; return false" />
```

I added the onClick part thinking that might help here's the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#send').click(function() {

            $('#waiting').show(500);
            $('#lginForm').hide(0);
            $('#message').hide(0);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'auction_seat_hwnd.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    pid: $('#pid').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#waiting').hide(500);
                    $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data.msg).show(500);
                    if (data.error === true) $('#loginForm').show(500);
                    else $('#send').hide(500);

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#waiting').hide(500);
                    $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error').text('There was an error.').show(500);
                    $('#loginForm').show(500);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting up a submit button, wiring an event handler with jQuery, and disabling it with a DOM Level 0 event:

```
<input class="nice-s" type="submit" id="send" name="login_submit" 
       style="width:150px"  value="GET SEATED" onClick="self.location=this.href; return false" />
```

Why not just use a regular button:

```
<input class="nice-s" type="button" id="send" name="login_submit" 
       style="width:150px"  value="GET SEATED" />
```

It won't ever cause your form to post, so you won't need that awful `onClick="self.location=this.href; return false"`, and the click handler you've set up will continue to work fine.

Comment: @AnariSengbe Please post an edit to your question, and list the html definition of the button that's posting back

Comment: @AnariSengbe - post the **actual html** of the button after you made the change.